# Adding arrow to Layout View in map of ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layouts, markers

To say it right at the beginning: I don't mean the North Arrow ;-)

In fact I have a map in the layout view which contains an orthophoto. On this orthophoto there is a little forest road and I want to insert an arrow at the edges of the map that shows where this road is going.

I have been searching for quite some time...how is that possible in ArcMap?

Here is a quick illustration of what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add an Arrow in Arcmap. This is what you need to do:
Using the Draw toolbar insert a straight line. Double click on the line and change its properties as illustrated in the [image: Graphic] below

Comment: Ah, cool, that's what I was looking for! Just one thing: Do you know if it is also possible to anchor this arrow to a certain geographic coordinate on my map?

Comment: I am not sure if that has been implemented in ArcMap

Comment: To "anchor this arrow to a certain geographic coordinate on my map" I would do exactly the same thing but in Data View - technically you will be anchoring it to those coordinates in the currently active data frame.

Comment: When adding arrows to a line FC it doesn't always look very nice, especially if you use a line that is a bit thicker. See my question here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75782/how-can-i-add-an-arrow-to-a-line

Answer (score 2):

You could also use insert North arrow to inset on the map and then covert it to Graphics and then do what you want to fix it

Comment: This is the correct answer if you want to generate arrows in ArcMap's Layout view at a specified angle with a mask. Masks don't work with arrows generated using the accepted answer. Converting to graphics was unnecessary in my case, you can specify the arrow"s angle and add a mask in the North Arrow's properties dialog box.

Comment: I have since move on to ArcGIS Pro now, so I don't work with ArcMap these days.  The reason I post mine was just another option to use it