# How to create Race Route with arrow directions and distance markers using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, markers, route

Anyone have any suggestions regarding how I would approach creating a race route with arrow directions and distance markers in ArcGIS? I could do it manually but I thought I recalled seeing something about a plug in that aided in this type of work.

Comment: you can use the cartographic line option for symbology to add regularly spaced arrows along a route. I think you would want to use the Linear referencing toolbox, and the 'locate features along routes' tool, to find distances along the route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding points along polyline: [Editor Tool](http://johndriessen.blogspot.com/2013/10/creating-mile-markers-its-fun-easy-and.html)

See this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10206/directional-flow-arrows-for-sewer-lines) for your directional arrows using a two layered symbol.

As to plugins, try [ET-Geowizards](http://www.ian-ko.com/)