# Labeling (one-way) streets in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, cartography, direction

I followed instructions in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/10208/36886) to [Creating Directional Flow Arrows for sewer lines?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10206) to add directional arrows to the one-way streets on a map I'm creating.

I've currently created a marker line with the standard arrow marker but there are a lot of one-way streets (and one-way street segments). So even with just a marker on the centerpoint of each line, I get something like the below image

[image]

I'm worried that if I dissolve streets together by name, that the direction of their drawing might get muddled (and the labels point in the wrong direction).

Do tutorials exist for labelling one-way streets in QGIS?

Comment: I would not suggest to dissolve by name. Streets might change driving direction in real world, and think of broad avenues consisting of thwo one-way-streets with some green in the middle.

Comment: Imho, your current approach is the only unambiguous way to label oneways. I'd recommend a more subtle symbol for the arrows but I wouldn't reduce their number.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to dissolve lines by name, as you can use the **Merge connected lines to avoid duplicate labels** option in the **Rendering** tab of **Labels**' options. This will reduce the number of labels, and helps to render long strings for roads composed from small segments.

[image]

There is also an option to add some extra characters to your labels to show the line direction. This option is in the **Formatting** tab of the **Labels**'s option. Check for the **Line direction symbol**.

[image]