# How to create a symbol with directional arrows in QGIS 3?

Tags: symbology, qgis-3, direction

This is the same as this question for ArcGIS: [Creating Directional Flow Arrows for sewer lines?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10206/creating-directional-flow-arrows-for-sewer-lines) but for QGIS.

I tried to follow the same approach as in ArcGIS, but I keep missing the mark.  I think I am close with a Marker Line.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you already got it.
Just change the following:

Instead of on `central point` select `with interval`:

[image]

And rotate your marker (or choose a different one):

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I missed that rotation box..that was key.